# linker failing to see frameworks from pods project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I was getting a linker error during build saying all the frameworks that my pods pulled in were missing when compiling the main project file.

To resolve I had to manually add each framework that the pods required:

[image]

To my project and the project compiled successfully.

Why is that?

Here's one guess but I don't know what I need to do to resolve it, the 3rd party library I'm using requires these linker flags:

[image]

I'd like to not have the frameworks repeated in the Pods and the main project.  What do I need to set in the linker flags to resolve this?  (I'm guessing the linker flags are the issue because I've never had this issue with these pods in any other project).